# CartThrob incorrect entry date format for Purchased items

Tags: cartthrob

I have EE 3.3.3 and CartThrob 3.0.2. The entry date for purchased items is not formatted. They appear e.g. 1466609887. Is this a bug or I need to fix a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has always looked like that in the Control Panel, because that's how the database stores dates, as unix timestamps.

But if you want it formatted nicely in a template, you can apply all of EE's [standard date formatting](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/date_variable_formatting.html) tricks, e.g
`{item:entry_date format="%F %d %Y"}`